# C++ lock a code excution for a scoped block

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to implement a lock on a scoped block. I found std::lock_guard implementing the same:

[std::lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)

States that

> attempts to take ownership of the mutex it is given. When control
> leaves the scope in which the lock_guard object was created, the
> lock_guard is destructed and the mutex is released

But again it states here

> If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the
> behavior is undefined: for example, the program may deadlock.

[std::mutex::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock)

Does the std::mutex::lock is called internally by std::lock_guard - I have a scenario that a callback will call a member method when a data arrives on a port - it is expected that data can arrive in multiples, when concerned method is getting executed by one callback?

Comment: The [constructor page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard) clearly states it tries to lock the mutex.

Comment: lock_guard is a RAI (SBRM) wrapper around `mutex::lock/mutex::unlock`, and sematics follow the rules of the mutex. Yes, it is undefined behavior to relock the `mutex` in the same thread, but it is allowed to relock `std::recoursive_mutex`.

Comment: Could you explain your scenario a bit more? How can this callback be called by the thread that is currently processing the callback? Usually either a different thread would handle the second callback or the second callback would not be invoked until the first callback finished. (Your situation is not impossible, just unusual in my experience.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `lock_guard` calls `lock()` to lock the mutex. (How else could it work?) If you think a thread might recursively lock a `std::mutex`, either through `lock_guard` or directly, you should use `std::recursive_mutex` instead, which does not have that weakness.

Comment: Better yet, fix the design. Recoursive mutex is without exception a sign of a terrible, terrible design

Comment: Thanks but what is the best locking mechanism to implement in my scenario

Comment: @Programmer your scenario is not clear at all, unfortunately.

Comment: @Programmer You always should use lock guards in preference of manual locking. RAII rulez.

Comment: I have a scenario that a callback will call a member method when a data arrives on a port - it is expected that multiple data can arrive at same time one by one when the member method in concern is getting executed